# In Firebase Database, How do I get the unique ID when I know the value?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

My database looks similar to this:

[image]

I'm trying to get the ID that is highlighted below. I already know "Item 2" but getting the key is confusing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `orderByValue` in that case.

Something like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase(app: app).reference().child("/data")
  .orderByValue().equalTo("Item 2").onChildAdded.forEach((event) => {
    print(event.snapshot.key)
});
```

Comment: Frank, many thanks. I got this to work by using "dataSnapshot.value.keys" instead of "event.snapshot.value". Second time you have helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Oh right, good point on `.key`, since that's what you're looking for! I updated it in my answer too.